# Download file in Electron and Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I have public url to XLSX file.

It is something like:

```
http://example.com/myfile.xslx
```

I'm trying to download this file and store it on my PC.

So what I'm doing is making a GET request to `http://example.com/myfile.xslx` and getting the content of the file and store it in a file.

```js
this.http.get('http://example.com/myfile.xslx', { responseType: 'blob' })
  .subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response); // this returns {size: 508079, type: "application/xlsx"}
   // here goes the code for writing content into file
});
```

The problem is I can't get the content of the file.

What I can get is only an object:

```js
{ size: 508079, type: "application/xlsx" }
```

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How, I solved it:

```
this.http.get('http://example.com/myfile.xslx', { responseType: 'blob' })
  .subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response); // this returns {size: 508079, type: "application/xlsx"}
   // here goes the code for writing content into file

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

    reader.onload = (data) => {
      const csvData = reader.result;
      console.log(csvData); // here I get contect of file using file reader
});
```

So solution was in FileReader().

Answer (score 0):

**Whats going on**

1. What your getting is probably a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), a Blob has these 2 properties (`size` and `type`), however it has some methods to read its contents.
2. .XSLX files are not text files but binary files, and they can't be easily read like text files.

**Possible solutions**

1. If it makes sense in your case you can use .CSV format instead of .XLSX, CSV files are text files and can be read with the `blob.text()` method.
2. You can try to read and write to it with a JavaScript-xslx library
   like [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) from SheetJS, or something similar.

With js-xlsx it would be something like this:

```
this.http.get('http://example.com/myfile.xslx', {  responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
.subscribe((response) => {
   let xslx = XLSX.read(response, {type:"array"});
   console.log(xslx);

// here goes the code for writing content into file

})
```

Comment: Thanks @Mendy I'll try this in morning and let you know.

Comment: I solved it using FileReader but your answer gave me idea definitely so thanks once again.